# Cant set textLabel because it contradicts parseDouble

Tags: java, swing, parsing

I have an ItemListener that looks like this:

```
private class Listener implements ItemListener
{
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e)
    {
        calculate();
    }
}
```

At the bottom of my `calculate()` method, I set these labels like this:

```
subtotalLbl.setText("\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tSubtotal:\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t " + String.valueOf(determinedSubTotal + priceIncrease) + "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t");
taxLbl.setText("\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\tTax:\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t " + String.valueOf(determinedTax + priceIncrease) + "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t");
totalLbl.setText("\t\t\t\t\t\t\tTotal:\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t " + String.valueOf(determinedTotal + priceIncrease) + "\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t");
```

Then I have an ActionListener that uses the text from the `totalLbl` for parseDouble

```
private class BtnClicked implements ActionListener
{       
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        String input = totalLbl.getText().trim();
        Double parsedString = Double.parseDouble(input) * 0.20; 

        Object src = e.getSource();

        if(src == submit)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Thank you for your order - the tip will be " + fmt.format(parsedString), "Thank you" , JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }
        else if(src == cancel)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Order was canceled" ,"Order Canceled" , JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }
    }
```

Obviously the program is crashing at the line inside of the `BtnClicked`'s `actionPerformed` method where `parseDouble(input)` is at, because the `totalLbl` `JLabel` has "Total:" in it.. where else would I set this or how would I work around this? The "Total:" is required. (can't use `split()` )

Here's a screenshot of what the entire `JFrame` looks like, program crashes when clicking the **submit** button:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create two `JLable`s, one which says `Total:` the other which actually holds the total value.

So your total calculation would look more like...

```
totalLblText.setText("Total:");
totalLbl.setText(String.valueOf(determinedTotal + priceIncrease));
```

Then you won't need to care.

You should make better use of your layout managers in order to support the formatting your trying to achieve rather than using formatting characters like `\t`, these will always end up in a mess

**Updated with layout example**

This simple example demonstrates how you might use a layout managers (and a technique known as compound layouts) and relieve the need to try and use a single label for displaying more information then it should...

[image: Layout Example]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import javax.swing.JCheckBox;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class TestLayout {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestLayout();
    }

    public TestLayout() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JTextField numberOfPizzas;
        private JCheckBox pepperoni;
        private JCheckBox sausage;
        private JCheckBox peppers;
        private JCheckBox onions;
        private JCheckBox mushrooms;
        private JCheckBox extracheese;

        private JLabel lblSubTotal;
        private JLabel lblTax;
        private JLabel lblTotal;

        public TestPane() {

            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.gridwidth = 1;
            gbc.weightx = 1;
            gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;

            JPanel header = new JPanel();
            JPanel extras = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
            JPanel totals = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

            add(header, gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(extras, gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            add(totals, gbc);

            numberOfPizzas = new JTextField(5);
            header.add(new JLabel("Number of pizzas"));
            header.add(numberOfPizzas);

            gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

            pepperoni = new JCheckBox("Pepperoni");
            sausage = new JCheckBox("Sausage");
            peppers = new JCheckBox("Peppers");
            onions = new JCheckBox("Onions");
            mushrooms = new JCheckBox("mushrooms");
            extracheese = new JCheckBox("Extra Cheeses");

            JCheckBox left[] = new JCheckBox[] {pepperoni, peppers, mushrooms};
            JCheckBox right[] = new JCheckBox[] {sausage, onions, extracheese};

            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.WEST;
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            add(left, extras, 0, 1, gbc);
            gbc.gridx = 1;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            add(right, extras, 0, 1, gbc);

            gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.weightx = 1;
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;
            gbc.anchor = GridBagConstraints.EAST;
            gbc.insets = new Insets(2, 12, 2, 12);

            totals.add(new JLabel("Subtotal:"), gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            totals.add(new JLabel("Tax:"), gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            totals.add(new JLabel("Total:"), gbc);

            gbc.weightx = 0;
            gbc.gridx = 1;
            gbc.gridy = 0;

            lblSubTotal = new JLabel("8.0");
            lblTax = new JLabel("0.78");
            lblTotal = new JLabel("8.78");

            totals.add(lblSubTotal, gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            totals.add(lblTax, gbc);
            gbc.gridy++;
            totals.add(lblTotal, gbc);

        }

        protected void add(JComponent[] comps, JComponent parent, int deltaX, int deltaY, GridBagConstraints gbc) {

            for (JComponent comp : comps) {
                parent.add(comp, gbc);
                gbc.gridy += deltaY;
                gbc.gridx += deltaX;
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Absolutely, I'm getting deep into iOS and Android application development:) This is great material for me to use.

Answer (score 1):

Lots of different ways to do this, the easiest is probably:

```
String[] parts = totalLbl.getText().split(":");
String input = parts[1].trim();
Double parsedString = Double.parseDouble(input) * 0.20;
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do this

```
str = str.replaceAll("\\D+","");
```

this will delete non digits from the string
so you would want it to be like this

```
 Double parsedString = Double.parseDouble(input.replaceAll("\\D+","")*0.20);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use separate widgets for the label and the value. E.g. The total label, create a JLabel object and set the text with static value "Total:", then for the total value, create a JTextField object and set the text with the actual value. When submitting, get the value from the textfield instead of from the label. Don't forget to call setEditable(false) to the textfield because the textfield is meant to display the value only, not to accept input.